# Pass a variable in another variable within an awk

Tags: awk

I have the below variables:

```
grep_line_new_file='create table "informix".issue'
new_file_below=`awk 'BEGIN { FS="\n[()]"; RS=";" } /$grep_line_new_file/ { print ")"$NF";"}' test`
```

Inside test file I have the below:

```
create table "informix".issue 
(
issue_no serial not null constraint "informix".nnc_issue00,
user_logged varchar(8,1) not null constraint "informix".nnc_issue01,
issue_status_code integer not null constraint "informix".nnc_issue02,
issue_cat_code varchar(2) not null constraint "informix".nnc_issue03,
issue_descr text not null constraint "informix".nnc_issue04,
issue_feedback text,
user_action varchar(8,1),
date_logged date not null constraint "informix".nnc_issue05,
date_compl date
) in datadbs extent size 16 next size 16 lock mode row;

revoke all on "informix".issue from "public" as "informix";
```

I am having an issue using an external variable to find and get the line below I need when echoing the "$new_file_below".

I have tried using the below [awk -v]. It still does not want to work:

```
new_file_below=`awk -v val="$grep_line_new_file" 'BEGIN { FS="\n[()]"; RS=";" } /$val/ { print ")"$NF";"}' test`
```

The outcome I need from the "new_file_below" variable is below:

```
) in datadbs extent size 16 next size 16 lock mode row;
```

Comment: Again, you had the question tagged with both [linux] and [hp-ux] while the question itself seems to be more about awk (and possibly shell), instead of being specific to either of the OS's. Let alone both at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to pass a variable in a pattern within a variable within an awk:

```
grep_line_new_file='create table "informix".issue'
new_file_below=`awk 'BEGIN { FS="\n[()]"; RS=";" } /'"$grep_line_new_file"'/ { print ")"$NF";"}' test`
```

output:

```
create table "informix".issue
) in datadbs extent size 16 next size 16 lock mode row;
```